# How to verify jwt token in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, ed25519, nimbus-jose-jwt, eddsa

I want to implement JWT verification in my spring boot application. The algorithm we used for signing token is Ed25519\EDDSA .

I don't find right dependency/library to implement Jwt verifier using ED25519 algorithm.

Can someone suggest maven dependency to validate JWT token ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer comes late but I just tried to solve the same problem and decided to share my conclusions.

I'd use [Spring Security with the OAuth 2.0 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) to validate JWTs.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, Spring Security's default JWT Decoder `NimbusJwtDecoder` does not support EdDSA (see [list of supported signature algorithms](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-jose/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jose/jws/SignatureAlgorithm.java). You will have to write your own `JWTDecoder`.

Luckily, Spring Security depends on [Nimbus JOSE+JWT library](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/download) that already supports EdDSA. To validate an EdDSA signature with the library, add the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.crypto.tink</groupId>
  <artifactId>tink</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Your code will at some point call the following lines, where `encodedJwt` is the encoded jwt string.

```java
SignedJWT signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(encodedJwt);

JWSVerifier verifier = new Ed25519Verifier(publicJWK);
assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));
```

The complete example can be found here: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-eddsa

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how the JWTDecoder would look, are you able to post it? Thank you!

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I cleaned up my system and don't have the POC anymore. I did an implementation without Spring that you can find here: https://github.com/curityio/oauth-filter-for-java/pull/6